# Cant access LeadStatus records from within managed package

Tags: apex, appexchange

We are using the following SOQL statement in out managed package which was working, but for the past week or so it started throwing error because there are no records returned.

```
SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted = true LIMIT 1
```

I can see the records when run from developer console.

But when i check with debug logs, No records are returned.

Has there anything changed in recent updates relating to LeadStatus object as this functionality was working fine earlier

Comment: If you execute the query in the Execute anonymous window of the developer console, the query is executed in User mode. Could it be possible that you have no access to the existing record?

Comment: I have administrator access, so when the query is executed, results are returned. But when the same user is running the managed package page, there are no results

Comment: Where are you executing the query when you are outside the page?

Comment: from dev console.

Comment: I run the query from dev console, it returns records, but when the VF page is run from managed package by the same user it returns no records

Comment: When you say dev console, you're talking about the query editor?

Comment: Yes , thats correct

Comment: I think the query editor run in system mode. It means that it ignores user permissions. Whereas, if your page use a standard controller it respects user permissions. Or also, if the controller specify the `With sharing` keyword, the sharing rules are applied to the user. So you should check the sharing settings.

Comment: The user who is running is administrator and has access to all records.